# CKeditor Firefox drag and drop encoding

Tags: firefox, encoding, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

Running into problems with CKeditor 4.5.6 involving dragging content into ckeditor's editor.
To be more precise, When dragging and dropping content from outside of the current browser window the content is either stripped of formatting (from Word for example) or converted to other language symbols (if from a browser for example). For instance dragging the 'Similar Questions' title from the page I'm typing this question in produces:

[Example of Firefox/CKeditor problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18HTN.png)

However, dropping the url in the url bar for instance works correctly.
This issue only appears in Firefox. Chrome and IE work fine and I can drop formatted text from anywhere including Word and only my accepted tags (using CKeditors content filter) will correctly make it into the editor.
My page is using UTF-8, the pages I'm dragging from also use UTTF-8.

I've exhausted the forums looking for a solution and would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks!

UPDATE:
After tinkering around in FF's console and exploring the drop event object I used the code:

```html
CKEDITORSETTINGS.ckeditor.document.on('drop', function (evt) { 
  var data = evt.data.$.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'); 
  console.log("paste data: " + data); 
});
```

Which shows that the paste data is also incorrect. So this looks to be a Firefox issue unless I find any more leads.

Update #2:
Narrowed down further: this issue is ONLY when dropping data from OTHER browsers into FF

Update #3:
Updated FF to current version (45.0) and the issue is resolved.
What a wild goose-chase!